# error 40: the type integer is not qualified with a namespace or alias

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, integer, int, edmx

Okay, this both a question and a solution.  I was having a problem deploying a solution which very simply used linq and EF to query a couple DB2 tables and display the results to a datagridview.  It worked fine on the development machine, but on the two other machines I tried, I would get "error 40: the type integer is not qualified with a namespace or alias."

After two days of trying various solutions, I decided to try debugging on one of the other machines.

Development machine is Windows XP with Visual Studio 2010.
Deployment machines both Windows 7 with VS 2010.

Well, I immediately noticed that on the deployment machine, VS would give me a list of errors (integer not qualified etc.) which weren't showing on my development machine.  The next thing I noticed was that when I double-clicked the .edmx file in the solution, it opened in xml instead of the visual display of the tables which I was using.

In this xml, every property/table column with a type of "integer" was underlined.  Well, that doesn't make sense.  Could this VS2010 not recognize the data type which was automatically generated by the other VS2010? Just out of desperation, I changed every instance of "Type='integer'" to "Type='int'"  It debugged and ran on all 3 machines like a charm.

So, my questions are:
1) Is this a bug that exists between the two development environments (XP vs. W7) or do I have my development environment set up incorrectly?
2) On my XP machine, how can I edit my .edmx file in the xml view?  Is it possible from within VS, or must I use a text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Is there an include file for your edmx which defines the "integer" type on your development machine (or a difference in framework version)? It works when you switch to int as it is a primitive type and does not need to be defined. I've only done code first so this is not a strength for me, but I think your error message is giving you a good hint. There is no definition of the object integer in the edmx (or include files) on the other two environments. On your dev machine I think this must either exist as:

1. A definition of an integer object somewhere in the edmx/include files
2. An alias of integer to int somewhere in these same files
3. A different version of .NET of EF which recognizes integer out of the box?

Comment: My .edmx file is completely auto-generated.  The entire project is pretty simple.  One windows form, one .edmx, one program.cs.  No out of the ordinary or custom includes or dlls.  The only reference which isn't standard is for DB2 (IBM.Data.DB2).

Comment: I just checked one of the deployment machines.  It's running .Net Framework 4.0 (same as development machine), but the deployment machine is 64bit.  Development is 32.  Could that be the issue?